# What's the most efficient way to get Library Items with associated metadata from a taxonomy?

Tags: c#, ektron

I have a site that's running Ektron v8.7 sp2.  There is a taxonomy that has library items, and those library items have metadata assigned to them.  I've been trying to find an efficient way that I can get all library items and their associated metadata from a particular taxonomy.

1. The `ContentManager` class in the FrameworkAPI does not return Library Items.
2. The `LibraryManager` class in the FrameworkAPI has two methods for getting individual items, but these would require an API call for each item in the taxonomy, which does not seem very efficient.

   - `LibraryManager.GetItem()` - returns LibraryData with MetaData (`Ektron.Cms.ContentMetaData[]`) and Taxonomies (`Ektron.Cms.TaxonomyBaseData[]`) populated
   - `LibraryManager.GetLibraryItemByContentId()` - returns LibraryData but MetaData and Taxonomies are both null
3. The `LibraryManager` class also has a `GetList()` method, but it doesn't meet my needs:

   - its criteria parameter does not allow specifying a taxonomy id.
   - if i already have a list of library item ids, there is no way of specifying that i want the method to return metadata (like there is on the ContentManager).

I'd prefer a way to get the data via the Framework API, but I'd also appreciate anything that uses Ektron's legacy APIs.  The data is there, and I can get it, but I'm looking for an efficient way to do so.

Comment: I'm using v8.7 sp2, and in the "Assign Item(s) to Taxonomy" screen of the workarea there is a Type dropdown.  The options in this dropdown are: all types, content, library, and archived content.  What version were you using where you couldn't add library items to taxonomy folders, rf_wilson?  Or were you just assuming it couldn't be done?  The data is all there for what I need, I just can't easily get to it without writing a custom SQL script.  And custom SQL is what I want to avoid, hence the question.  As it stands, I'm going to be moving away from the library and towards the DMS.

Comment: As far as adding metadata to library items, you just assign the metadata fields to the corresponding content folder, and when you add/edit library items those metadata fields are available.  `LibraryManager.GetItem()` returns the library item with its metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking with the APIs, I'm not sure there is an efficient way to mesh all of that data together.

This is another argument, though, for using the DMS and not the Library. The DMS will treat the files as content and allow you to use the ContentManager in all its glory. The Library is a simple tool for simple management, the DMS / ContentManager is much stronger for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: do you know what plans (if any) there are to enhance support for Library Items in future versions of the Framework API?  There are some cases where it's more convenient for an image to be a library item, but it would be nice to be able to get metadata, taxonomy assignments, etc. via the Framework API.

Comment: I don't know whether any plans currently exist to enhance that particular use-case, but I did bring it up with the engineering team.